# OpenWeather One Call API coord not loading

Tags: ios, json, swift, decode, openweathermap

In my Weather app, I call the OpenWeather One Call API.
In my Xcode debug console, I get:

```
Error getting weather: keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "coord", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"coord\", intValue: nil) (\"coord\").", underlyingError: nil))
```

I tested this app on a Simulator and Physical Device. Doesn't work.

Please give me information on how to fix this. Really appreciate this.

Here is the part in my code where it parses the JSON:

```swift
class WeatherManager {
    // HTTP request to get the current weather depending on the coordinates we got from LocationManager
    func getCurrentWeather(latitude: CLLocationDegrees, longitude: CLLocationDegrees) async throws -> ResponseBody {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=\(latitude)&lon=\(longitude)&units=metric&appid=") else { fatalError("Missing URL") }


        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: urlRequest)
        
        guard (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode == 200 else { fatalError("Error while fetching data") }
        
        let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseBody.self, from: data)
        
        return decodedData
    }
}
```

Here is the first few parts of ResponseBody:

```swift
struct ResponseBody: Decodable {
    public let lat, lon: Double
    var weather: [WeatherResponse]
    var current: CurrentResponse
    var name: String
    var wind: WindResponse
    var sun: SunResponse

    struct WeatherResponse: Decodable {
        var id: Double
        var main: String
        var description: String
        var icon: String
    }
```

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: The error says, that your mapping goes wrong. Please, check the json you get in the response with your ResponseBody model. You could use [QUICKTYPE](https://quicktype.io/) to generate the model from your JSON.

Comment: Second: never share your APP ID key. your current is `appid=047ef9c3516e552807a6bbd0067851ce`, please, consider revoking it.

Comment: I.e. create a new API key for production.

Comment: Example json is here (I used your key): https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=40.148&lon=17.107&units=metric&appid=047ef9c3516e552807a6bbd0067851ce

Comment: In your `ResponseBody`, you should have `let lat, lon: Double` not `coord`.
Check out my `OpenWeather One Call API library` on github at: https://github.com/workingDog/OWOneCall  it has everything you need. There is also an example at: https://github.com/workingDog/OWOneCallExample

Comment: Now I am having another error. Apparently my "weather" parameter doesn't exist?

Error:
`Error getting weather: keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "weather", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"weather\", intValue: nil) (\"weather\").", underlyingError: nil))`

Comment: There is no "weather" at top level. Bu we can't guess exactly what's wrong without knowing what is `ResponseBody`.

Comment: Edit your question with that. It’s hard to read in comment. And it doesn’t seem to match the Json you are receiving

Comment: @Larme I have edited the question. Can you try reading now?

Comment: Let's do a little trick, let's do the reverse: Make them `Codable` instead of `Decodable`. Let's create an instance: `let response = ResponseBody.init(...)` (I let you complete it to make a good init of your ResponseBody with all the parameters). Then, let's encode it: let encodeJSON = try! JSONEncoder().encode(response); print("JSON:\n \(String(data: encoded, encoding: .utf8)"), and compare it with the response of the URL. You can use a JSON formatter to pretty print it (like JSONLint, etc.). Do they match? No, but the "encoded", is what is expecting your parser. That's the mismatch.

Comment: Your `ResponseBody`, does not match the json data. There is 
no `name`, no `wind`, no `sun`, no `weather` in the top level `OpenWeather One Call API` response.
Look at my code in my library at: https://github.com/workingDog/OWOneCall, specifically `OWResponse`. It has all you need to 
decode the API response into swift models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenWeatherMap is [well documented](https://openweathermap.org/api/one-call-api), please read the docs.

There are multiple different APIs, I guess your struct represents another API data.

The basic *OneCall* root object (omitting `minutely`, `daily`, `hourly` and `alerts`) is

```
struct OneCall: Decodable {
    let lat, lon: Double
    let timezone : String
    let timezoneOffset : Int
    let current: Current
}
```

And the descendants `Current` and `Weather` are

```
struct Current: Decodable {
    let dt, sunrise, sunset : Date
    let temp, feelsLike, dewPoint, uvi, windSpeed : Double
    let pressure, humidity, clouds, visibility, windDeg : Int
    let windGust : Double?
    let weather : [Weather]
}

struct Weather: Decodable, Identifiable, CustomStringConvertible {
    let id : Int
    let main, description, icon : String
}
```

`dt`, `sunrise` and `sunset` are decoded as `Date` and the snake_case keys are converted to camelCase by applying appropriate decoding strategies.

I highly recommend to build the URL with `URLComponents` and `URLQueryItems`, `apiKey` is the API key constant.

```
let apiKey = "•••••••••"

enum WeatherManagerError : Error { case missingURL, badResponse }

class WeatherManager {
    // HTTP request to get the current weather depending on the coordinates we got from LocationManager
    func getCurrentWeather(latitude: CLLocationDegrees, longitude: CLLocationDegrees) async throws -> OneCall {

        var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall")!
        let queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "appid", value: apiKey),
                          URLQueryItem(name: "lat", value: "\(latitude)"),
                          URLQueryItem(name: "lon", value: "\(longitude)"),
                          URLQueryItem(name: "units", value: "metric")]
        urlComponents.queryItems = queryItems
        guard let url = urlComponents.url else { throw WeatherManagerError.missingURL }
        
        let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
        
        guard (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode == 200 else { throw WeatherManagerError.badResponse }
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .secondsSince1970
        return try decoder.decode(OneCall.self, from: data)
    }
}
```